# convert data.table (or data.frame) to yaml and then back to its original format

Tags: r, yaml

I would like to convert a data.table (data.frame also does) to yaml format and then convert this yaml back to the original format, but there is no access to original data.frame any longer. Tried `data.table()`, `as.data.table()` (and their data.frame equivalents) all fail.

MWE:

```
library(data.table)
library(yaml)

foo <- rbindlist(list(
data.table(env = "default", a = "low", x = "A", z = "low", i =  1, j = 1, k = 1),
data.table(env = "default", a = "low", x = "A", z = "medium", i =  1, j = 2, k = 1),
data.table(env = "default", a = c("low", "medium", "high"), x = "A", z = "high", i =  2, j = 1, k = 1),
data.table(env = "other", a = c("low", "medium", "high"), x = "B", z = "na", i =  2, j = 2, k = 2)
))
out <- split(replace(foo, "env", NULL), foo$env)
out <- as.yaml(out)
# cat(out)

# foo is no longer available
# rm(foo)

bar <- yaml::yaml.load(out, as.named.list = T)

# how to make bar same as foo, i.e. as follows:
#        env      a x      z i j k
# 1: default    low A    low 1 1 1
# 2: default    low A medium 1 2 1
# 3: default    low A   high 2 1 1
# 4: default medium A   high 2 1 1
# 5: default   high A   high 2 1 1
# 6:   other    low B     na 2 2 2
# 7:   other medium B     na 2 2 2
# 8:   other   high B     na 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `as.yaml` destroys the attributes, which is what distinguishes a data.frame from a list in `R`:

```
library(data.table)
library(yaml)

foo <- rbindlist(list(
  data.table(env = "default", a = "low", x = "A", z = "low", i =  1, j = 1, k = 1),
  data.table(env = "default", a = "low", x = "A", z = "medium", i =  1, j = 2, k = 1),
  data.table(env = "default", a = c("low", "medium", "high"), x = "A", z = "high", i =  2, j = 1, k = 1),
  data.table(env = "other", a = c("low", "medium", "high"), x = "B", z = "na", i =  2, j = 2, k = 2)
))
```

This is what the attributes should look like.

```
> attributes(foo)
$`names`
[1] "env" "a"   "x"   "z"   "i"   "j"   "k"  

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$class
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

$.internal.selfref
<pointer: 0x0000000002521ef0>
```

And this is what they do look like.

```
foo2 <- as.yaml(foo)
# cat(out)
bar <- yaml::yaml.load(foo2)

> attributes(bar)
$`names`
[1] "env" "a"   "x"   "z"   "i"   "j"   "k"
```

So the conversion to data.frame is as easy as:

```
attributes(bar)$class <- "data.frame"
attributes(bar)$row.names <- seq_along(bar[, 2])
```

Or to data.table:

```
attributes(bar)$class <- "data.frame"
bar <- as.data.table(bar)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, once converted to yaml there is no access to foo, the original data.frame anymore. Will edit my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Not sure why you would need access to `foo`. You just need to change the class of `bar` and add `row.names` if you want a proper `data.frame`.

Comment: Sorry late was comprehending something else... neverthless you are missing one line from my above MWE, that is `out <- split(replace(foo, "env", NULL), foo$env)`. Without it, it is actually as simple as doing a `setDT` or `setDF` on reading them as a named list, i.e. `setDT(yaml::yaml.load(out, as.named.list = T))`, where `out = foo2` in your answer.